# Docker container xdebug with phpstorm issues

Tags: vmware, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I need to debug (with phpstorm + xdebug) some php code inside a docker machine running on a vmware virtual machine.
The IDE is running on another vmware virtual machine.

I have some problems with xdebug:

- when setting a breakpoint other than the first line, is ignored
- when setting a breakpoint on the first line, it stops at the breakpoint; clicking the "step over" button (F8) exits debug and hangs the browser until I stop the debug with "stop process" button
- when setting a breakpoint on the first line, it stops at the breakpoint; clicking the "resume program" button (F9) with no nore breakpoints, exits debug and finish loading the page
- when setting a breakpoint on the first line, it stops at the breakpoint; clicking the "resume program" button (F9) with another breakpoint set, it won't hit the breakpoint and hangs the browser

Docker container xdebug config

```
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.2.80 //client IP
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

I cannot understand where I should investigate.

Could please someone give me some hint?

Thank you
Alex